# Use \DeclareUnicodeCharacter with combined Unicode characters

Tags: pdftex, unicode, unicode-math, newunicodechar

How is it possible to use combined Unicode characters (such as x̃, x̅, X̅, f̅, f᷉, f̂) in a definition of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`?

So something like `\newunicodechar{x̃}{\tilde{x}}` (using the package `newunicodechar`) or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00780303}{\tilde x}` would be nice.

Comment: basically you can not. Supporting combining characters in pdftex is really hard.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. It is a pity pdftex cannot handle this ‘simple’ character input :-(

Comment: tex typesets characters as they appear, and once typeset they are not accessible from within tex. so it typesets an x, then sees a combining accent but can do nothing with it.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard, bordering impossible, to support unicode combining characters with pdftex.

This is not much of a problem in practice as (if using luatex is not an option) you can usually pre-process to handle the combinations.

For example if instead of using pdflatex directly you use `myscript` which is

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)\xcc\x83/\\tilde{\1}/g' \
    -e 's/\(.\)\xcc\x85/\\bar{\1}/g' \
    -e 's/\(.\)\xe1\xb7\x89/\\acute{\\grave{\\acute{\1}}}/g' \
    -e 's/\(.\)\xcc\x82/\\hat{\1}/g' \
    $1 > $1-

pdflatex $1-
```

then with `file.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$x̃, x̅, X̅, f̅, f᷉, f̂$

\end{document}
```

the command `myscript file.tex` produces

[image]

The script is written using bash syntax but a .bat file for windows could be used with a suitable windows sed (or perl or python)

Comment: U+1dc9 COMBINING ACUTE-GRAVE-ACUTE should be horizontally stacked like ``'`'``  but that's just details, it is a never used character anyway in math, did you intend  U+0304 COMBINING TILDE `~` ???